# How to avoid lots of booleans

Tags: architecture, game-state

This was probably asked somewhere but I can't google anything for some reason.
So I'm making a puzzle game as a result I have lots of booleans which affect the game only once and become redundant. 
As an example, to enter some door player needs to pickup a key so there is check for that. After that when hero enters a doors for the first there is a special animation triggered.
So after player had entered the door  this checks are no longer neccery.

I am not worried about perfomance but rather code design.
Maybe there is some clever trick to manage game state without bunch of ifs and bools?

Comment: This is an implementation question, please specify the relevant language and framework. Please spend _significantly_ more time researching before asking a question.

Comment: @user3730788 


I don't understand why it's an implementation question. I'm asking for a theory or a guidline or general advice and not an implementation. Definitely not one that is specific for some language or framework. That beeing said i'm develoing with Godot and Gdscript. I would like to spend more time on research but I don't know where to look. So maybe you could point me some direction.

Comment: I agree with Argus Kos, there's a decent amount we can say about addressing this problem in an engine/language-agnostic way, as the two answers so far demonstrate. That said, it would be useful to have a bit more idea of the general strategy you're using thus far. Are you hard-coding these variables in your program's source code / scripts, or do they exist in the level data in some way?

Comment: @DMGregory
I will try to explain breefly without going into too much details.
I have two json files one with a state of the world where I have set of locations and the current state of location. I also have separate json file with the hero state.
There is no separation on quests in this files. It's just data. 
In code I just look up for a current state of the world and the hero and then decide what to do.
The game is not linear but I think the main problem of bifield idea is that one state can be used in diffenert places by diffrenet "quests" or parts of the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oldschool RPGs with lots of these switch/lock-and-key style steps but a strictly linear progression would often implement this as a "Quest Stage" integer or enumeration.

Let's imagine a linear dungeon with a key to open the entrance door, two rooms of puzzles to solve, and a boss to defeat:

- the dungeon's quest stage begins at `0 == QUEST_START`
- finding the entrance key sets the stage to `1 == KEY_FOUND`
- the door opens if you interact with it and the quest stage is 1.

  - This sets the stage to `2 == DOOR_OPEN`. If you come back to this map with quest stage >= 2, the door spawns already-open.
- solving the first puzzle sets the quest stage to `3 == FIRST_PUZZLE`

  - with the quest stage at 3 or greater, the door to the next room opens
- solving the second puzzle sets the quest stage to `4 == BOSS`

  - now the boss door will open
- defeating the boss sets the quest stage to `5 == DUNGEON_COMPLETE`

  - all the villagers can check if the quest stage is >= 5 to say "Thank you for defeating the boss monster!'

Here we had 5 boolean tests (has key, has opened door, has solved puzzle 1, 2, has defeated boss) packed into a single number we can store in 3 bits rather than 5 bools. In 16 bits we could store 16 independent booleans as a bitfields, or distinguish 65535 stages of a linear sequence (which might have been significant back in the day of tiny on-cartidge save game storage)

Even though the storage efficiency isn't so relevant today, it can still help tame the explosion of variables you need to keep track of to describe the game state. (Hopefully these aren't hard coded in your program, but even the conceptual overhead for your level designer can be improved by this kind of reduction)

The obvious limitation is that it's linear. This style of tracking doesn't work at all for optional objectives/events the player could skip, or choice points where the player can do multiple things in any order. For those you need to fall back on individual flags.

This also means all your indices may have to shift around whenever you insert/remove/rearrange these beats in your level & mission design. (But hopefully you're implementing this in a data-driven way, where you just specify the dependency relationships in your level/quest markup and they're numbered for you) This can invalidate save files from before the change.

You can get some benefit from using a separate quest stage variable for each linear branch of a quest chain/tree. This lets you have branching and limits the amount of spillover effects when one branch gets redesigned, while still getting a modest reduction in the amount of state you're tracking.

Comment: OMG! A totally new and undiscovered method for storing boolean values as bits. What will we ever call such an innovative creation; the DMGregory method?!?!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @user3730788. This isn't a method for storing boolean values as bits — out of the 32 different possible states of 5 boolean variables, the method above only describes 6 of them (note the numbers don't go up by powers of 2 as with bitfield storage). So it"s not storing the booleans, just counting a sequence of steps. It's also not claimed to be original: I mention right at the start that this is a state tracking method used in old RPGs.

Comment: @user3730788 if you think the answer is not good enough, please let us know why and how to improve it, otherwise there is no point on leaving a comment. The method specified is one I've used in the past, and if done correctly, can lead to a nicely organised project. Also the point of this site is not to "discover new methods" of doing something, but more to help people come up to speed with methods already in use in the industry.

Answer (score -3):

Consider using a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). You can divide up the values into 8, 16, 32, or 64 bit segments.

Comment: I don't think a bit field helps with code maintaining at all. If anything it will probably make code a lot trickier to read.

Comment: Depends on the implementation and API. Your first step should be to do some research on existing options for your language.

Comment: The OP mentioned they are more concerned about code organisation/complexity than performance. Using bit fields is literally making the code less readable for squeezing performance out of everything.